# How to filter the input range for MAX with a value from another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for a formula that will return the value from column B from the row that contains the maximum value in column A ignoring values where column C contains the word 'ignore'.

```
    A  |  B  |  C 
1   4  | abc | 
2   6  | cde | 
3   3  | ghi | 
4   9  | jkl | ignore
```

So the example above would return `cde` as 6 is the maximum value in column A if row 4 is ignored.

However, I cannot seem to find the maximum from column A ignoring A4. I tried `=MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ignore",C:C)), 0, A:A))`, but this still returns '9'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AGGREGATE in a INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(AGGREGATE(14,6,$A$1:$A$4/($C$1:$C$4<>"ignore"),1),A:A,0))
```

The AGGREGATE is the part that returns the largest number where Column C does not equal `ignore`.

The match then finds that number in Column A and returns the row number to the INDEX.

So the whole returns the value in Column B where the value in Column A is the largest number that does not have Column C as `ignore`

[image]

Comment: Very clever, didn't immediately see how this worked. But you are dividing by one or zero depending on whether column C contains the word 'ignore' and ignoring cells with errors in the AGGREGATE function.